# Is there a way to install pykml with conda and python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.7, pykml

If I try to install pykml with conda I got the following conflict:

Specifications:

- pykml -> python[version='2.7.*|3.4.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|<3']

Your python: python=3.7

My question is now if there exist a way to install pykml in python3.7 and to avoid downgrading my version of python?

regards